# Matplotlib - savefig ignores facecolor when saving with transparency

Tags: python, matplotlib, background

I was surprised to find that when I use `savefig` with `transparent=True` this removed the `facecolor` which I might have set.

*How can I not lose any background colours I manually set (including white)?*

## Compare

### The GUI

[image]

### Using `transparent=False`

```
plt.savefig('temp.pdf', format='pdf', transparent=False, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

### Using `transparent=True`

```
plt.savefig('temp.pdf', format='pdf', transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

## MWE

```
import matplotlib as mpl

rc_fonts = {
    "text.usetex": True,
    'text.latex.preview': True,
    "font.size": 50,
    'mathtext.default': 'regular',
    'axes.titlesize': 55,
    "axes.labelsize": 55,
    "legend.fontsize": 50,
    "xtick.labelsize": 50,
    "ytick.labelsize": 50,
    'figure.titlesize': 55,
    'figure.figsize': (10, 6.5),  # 15, 9.3
    'text.latex.preamble': [
        r"""\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amssymb,bm,physics,mathtools,nicefrac,letltxmacro,fixcmex}
        """],
    "font.family": "serif",
    "font.serif": "computer modern roman",
}
mpl.rcParams.update(rc_fonts)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes, InsetPosition, mark_inset
from numpy import linspace, sin


x = linspace(0, 1, 100)
plt.clf()
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax2 = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1], label=str(2))
ip = InsetPosition(ax1, [0.08, 0.63, 0.45, 0.3])
ax2.set_axes_locator(ip)
ax1.plot(x, x)
ax1.plot(x, x + 0.3)
ax1.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 1)
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), backgroundcolor="white")
ax2.set_facecolor('grey')
ax1.set_yticks([])
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])
ax1.text(0.3, 0.3, '$1$', transform=ax1.transAxes, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', color='black', backgroundcolor='white')
```

## Desired output

I would like it so that any background colurs default to `None` (or similar), such that if it is unspecified, then it will be transparent, and if it is specified, then it will be respected and opaque. Hence I would like the following output (using a blue background for added clarity):

### What I would like:

[image]

Currently if I use `facecolor=(1,1,1,0)` it correctly removes all the colours around the margins, but the main plot area is still white.

Comment: Transparent, by definition, sets all axes backgrounds to transparent - hence the name. Why do you want to use it in the first place?

Comment: A few of my figures go on posters or websites with a coloured background, and it looks nicer if the background colour matches. (Albeit I then have to be a bit more weary about filling in any background colours, if any).

Comment: But on a poster you would want the figure background transparent, not the axes, right? Or should the main axes be transparent as well? I have an [open issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10939) about the savefig arguments being misleading; but there is a workaround for any case. If this does not become obvious from reading the issue, I could give an answer here, if you tell what elements should be transparent or removed and which not. Also how are you preparing the poster? Via tex? Or a graphics program?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest --- I have added an example of the desired output which hopefully makes this clearer (I think I am a bit confused about the figure/axis/plot areas). Your open issue has helped me get some of the way there, but not all. The poster is prepared using LaTeX, although for websites I would just output an appropriate image format that allows transparency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can achive the desired output via

```
ax1.set_facecolor((1,1,1,0))
ax2.set_facecolor("grey")
fig.savefig(__file__+".pdf", facecolor=(1,1,1,0))
```

Comment: This doesn't achieve the desired affect. If I place these four lines at the end (and have a leading `fig = plt.gcf()`  after the call to `plt.clf()`), then I get the main figure as still having a white and non-transparent background.

Comment: Right, I confused myself, and you as well, sorry about that. Now the code in the answer should work.

Comment: So in your opinion is this behaviour to be expected or not, and well documented or not? I realise you comment about `frameon` in your [linked issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10939) being misleading. Having to set all these `facecolor` values seems a little bit messy. If I followed your issue correctly this does seem like the job of `frameon`.

Comment: Yes. So I would like to change this behaviour, but I haven't put any effort into it yet. There is also a little controversity about whether to remove all the arguments to `savefig`, to which I would oppose.